# Renaming all files within subdirectories

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to rename all the files with certain regex patterns within the same subdirectory.  Right now, I am in the current directory (above all the sub directories) and am running the following code:

```
for d in */ ; do
    cp $d*hw4*.pl $dhw4.pl
done
```

I wish to find all the files with hw4 in them, and rename them to hw4.pl and keep them in the same directory.  Could someone assist me with this?  I know you can do this with the `mv` command, but I don't want to make a mistake, so I am using copy for now.

Thank you.

Comment: Trying to rename/copy multiple files to the same name? That just overwrites all but the last one renamed. Why not just delete all but one instead and rename it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to use `find`, like this:

```
find . -type f -name '*hw4*' -execdir mv {} hw4.pl \;
```

Comment: @DougMcMurray Glad to hear this. Note: in opposite to `-exec`, `-execdir` executes the command in the parent directory of the matched file. This makes it simple to _rename in the same folder_.